# posts overlapping

Tags: php, html, css

Now i dont know if this is simple or hard. If its just css or php code i need 
But basically i have posting system and users can comment on posts. In the comments page it shows orginal post and one users have left (the comments) 
I had one in there and this was fine but i added another and it looked like this...

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2fIXd.jpg 
As you can see its completly different! Heres my code for it...

```
<?php           
mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");      
mysql_select_db("test");           
echo "<a href='Untitled9.php'>Go Back...</a>"; 
?> 
<br/><br/> 

<div class="message">
<?php 
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM threads WHERE id = '". 
mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['id']) . "'") or die(mysql_error());         
 while($r = mysql_fetch_array($sql))  {         
 $posted = date("jS M Y h:i",$r['posted']); echo "".$r['author']." &nbsp; $posted"; ?> 
<a href="http://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button" data-count="horizontal" data-text="<?php echo "".$r['message'].""; ?>">
        Tweet</a><script type="text/javascript" src="http://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js"></script>
<div class="message2"><?php echo "&nbsp;".$r['message'].""; ?></div> 
<?php  echo "Likes: ".$r['votes_up']."&nbsp;"; echo "Dislike: ".$r['votes_down']."";>        
</div>
<br/>
<hr width="725px">

<?php    
echo "<h3>Replies...</h3>"; ?>
<div class="message"><?php          
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM replies WHERE thread = '".
mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['id']) . "'") or die(mysql_error());          
while($r = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {          
$posted = date("jS M Y h:i",$r['posted']); echo "".$r['author']." &nbsp; $posted"; ?>
<a href="http://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button" data-count="horizontal" data-text="<?php echo "".$r['message'].""; ?>">
        Tweet</a><script type="text/javascript" src="http://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js"></script>  
<div class="message2">
<?php echo "&nbsp;".$r['message']."" ; } ?> </div> 
</div>

<hr width="725px">

<form action="newreply.php" method="POST">      
Your Name: <input type="text" name="author">      
<input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $_GET['id']; ?>" name="thread"><br>      
Message:<br><textarea cols="60" rows="5" name="message"></textarea><br>      
<input type="submit" value="Post Reply">      
</form>
```

The code looks really messy on here. I tried editing but couldnt get much better.

 So bascially what i want to know is how do i prevent this (the overlapping) from happening?

Edit ***** CSS

```
.message {
width: 500px;
    color: black;
    background: white;
    padding:8px;
    border:1px solid white;
    margin:5px auto;
    -moz-border-radius:8px;
}   

.message2 {
background-color: grey;
}
```

It looks to me as though everything is posting inside the second php function but i have some code pretty much the same for just the individual post and this displays normally i.e. as many as i want. Im just wondering is there something i need to add/change

Comment: If it really is CSS related, it would be nice to see your CSS code.

Comment: well thats what im not sure. I will provide but im not sure if it is he problem..

Comment: Usually a `<div style="clear:both;"></div>` fixes these kinds of issues.

Comment: I would say it's more than likely a CSS problem! Got a link we can look at?

Comment: i updated with the only css for this

Comment: @madflow i tried what you said but it created a massive gap and posts disappeared

Comment: post the produced html and css, not php

Comment: @Sotiris what do you mean? i dont think the html is the problem i think its the php

Answer (score 0):

**Wrong** (Your code)**:**

```
<?php echo "&nbsp;".$r['message']."" ; } ?> </div> 
</div>
```

**Correct:**

```
<?php echo "&nbsp;".$r['message']."" ; ?> </div> 
</div>
<?php } ?>
```

You were opening multiple DIVs in your while loop but only closing two.

Comment: This has untangled them but if you refer back to my image in post. It displays posts one like normal and post to only the grey part. No white around it

Answer (score 0):

Similarly to Cobra_Fast's reply, it seems that the positioning of your divs seemed to be causing the problem, and also the position of your while loop.

Try replacing the replies section with the following and let me know if it is any better.

```
<?php    
echo "<h3>Replies...</h3>";          
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM replies WHERE thread = '".mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['id']) . "'") or die(mysql_error());          
while($r = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {   
    ?>
    <div class="message">       
    $posted = date("jS M Y h:i",$r['posted']); 
    echo $r['author']." &nbsp; ".$posted;
    ?>
    <a href="http://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button" data-count="horizontal" data-text="<?php echo $r['message']; ?>">
        Tweet</a><script type="text/javascript" src="http://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js"></script>
    </div>
    <div class="message2">
    <?php 
        echo "&nbsp;".$r['message'];
    ?>
    </div>
<?php   
}
?>
```