# redirect displays alert box

Tags: javascript, html

a page directs users back to a page automatically

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="1; URL=http://localhost/mywebsite/Untitled9.php">
```

when it reaches 'Untitled9.php' i want it to display an alert box saying 'Message sucessfully posted' 
I only want it to display when it id directed back to the page and not when first load 
e.g Home - Message page = No alert 
Home - message page - submit - redirect to message page = alert 'post sucessfully posted'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't control the DOM of a page externally.

What you could do however is pass a variable in the query string to the page you're redirecting to like this

Untitled9.php?message=success

Then on your new page have

```
<?php 
session_start();
if ($_GET['message'] == "success" && $_SESSION['revisit'] == "0")
{
    $_SESSION['revisit'] = "1";
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">window.alert('Message successfully posted.');</script>
    <?php
}
?>
```

In your first page change your code to look like this

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['revisit'] = "0";
?>
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="1; URL=http://localhost/mywebsite/Untitled9.php">
```

Comment: you answered worked thankyou! :) is there a way so the alert box only shows once as if i refresh page it alerts again

Comment: You could use sessions to keep a boolean to say if the user has been to that page before. You would need to reset it before you redirect them though.

Comment: I have no idea about how to do this haha

Comment: Updated my answer to reflect this

Comment: Thank you! thats great thanks!
Im also having a problem here ...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6677345/posts-overlapping
Could you take a look and see if you know how i can ressolve this please

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, this should work for you (assuming you alter the keys for the $_POST variables accordingly, of course):

```
<?php (isset($_POST['my_sub_btn'])): ?>
<script type="text/javascript">window.alert('Message successfully posted.');</script>
<?php endif ?>
```

Assuming you're submitting the message from a form, there should be no reason to redirect using a HTML redirect. Set the `action` attribute of your form to `Untitled9.php` and it will handle the rest...

Comment: should i add this to the 'Untitled9.php' page?

Answer (score 0):

Given your requirements, why not set a parameter on succes? Such as:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="1; URL=http://localhost/mywebsite/Untitled9.php?success=1">
```

Comment: It gives you a variable to check in order to display your alert.